# Giving writing permissions for IIS user at Windows 2003 Server

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, user-permissions, windows-2003-webserver

I am running a website over **Windows 2003 Server** and **IIS6** and I am having problems to write or delete files in some temporary folder obtaining this kind of warmings:

> Warning: unlink(C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\tmp\cache\persistent\myapp_cake_core_cake_): Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\lib\Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine.php on line 254

I went to the `tmp` directory and at the properties I gave the IIS User the following permissions:

- Read & Execute
- List folder Contents
- Read

And it still showing the same warnings.

When I am on the properties window, if I click on `Advanced` the IIS username appears twice.

One with **Allow** type and **read  & execute** permissions and the other with **Deny** type and **Special** permissions.

My question is:
Should I give this user not only the Read & Execute permissions but also this ones?:

- Create Attributes
- Create Files/ Write Data
- Create Folders/ Append Data
- Delete Subfolders and Files
- Delete

They are available to select if I Click on the `edit` button over the username.

Wouldn't I be opening a security hole if I do this?
Otherwise, how can I do to read and delete the files my website uses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I did was giving read/write/modify permissions on `app\tmp` folder for the *Internet Guest Account*.